# How can I detect the end of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arduino

I written a class, in which I gave a Pointer to the first element of an array. I don't know the size of this, but I need to know when I have the last Element.

At the moment I give an extra variable to the method, which contains the size of it. and I want to remove it.

My Method:

```
#define NOP //__asm__("nop\n\t")

//Setup the objekt
SR::SR(int DS, int SHCP, int STCP){
  pinMode(DS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHCP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(STCP, OUTPUT);
  this->_DS = DS;
  this->_SHCP = SHCP;
  this->_STCP = STCP;
}

//!!!!!!!!!!at "*muster" you have to send an pointer on the first element of an Array!!!!!!!!!!!

//to shift a Muster in the register

void SR::musterIn(bool *muster, int length){
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
    //set datapin
    digitalWrite(_DS, *(muster+i));

    //shift in register memory
    digitalWrite(_SHCP, HIGH);
    NOP;
    digitalWrite(_SHCP, LOW);
  }

  //set to output
  digitalWrite(_STCP, HIGH);
  NOP;
  digitalWrite(_STCP, LOW);
}
```

Thanks,
Flo

Comment: C does not support classes (i.e. C and C++ are not the same language).

Comment: _At the moment I give an extra variable to the method, which contains the size of it. and I want to remove it._ Why?

Comment: It depends, you can pass C arrays by reference and find their length with `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`. The other thing you can do is pack the length into a struct and pass the struct by reference. However, there's not really any practical or sane reason to do either of these things. If you have a pointer to the first element of an array, and it's length and you want to pass the array to be iterated then you already have an ideal function.

Comment: To detect the end of an array passed by the pointer to the first element, you basically either need to know its size, or to pass another pointer to the last or one-past-the-last element.

Comment: Instead of `*(muster+i)` it is more common to write `muster[i]`

Comment: why don't you know the size of that array? you're on an Arduino. Any array that is already in memory has a known length because you created it, anything you read from outside the Arduino can be counted while reading. I don't see any reason to handle unknown array lengths in a mcu. you have limited memory so you have to keep track of sizes anyway.

Comment: @TotZam so there is no Way, did i get it right? If yes how did it `size of` whith an array?

Comment: @Piglet because I want to make an Libraray out of this. and it could be that anyone needs more elements or less elements.

Comment: yeah but then they know the number of elements and you still don't need a dynamic solution because you can simply ask them for the length. I haven't tryied in on hardware but my pretty outdated Arduino IDE compiles ranged for loops, maybe give it a try

Comment: @Piglet yes thats I'm doing right now, but in my opinon it would be nice if i don't have to ask. because it make it easy to use the libraray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way, then to pass the length information to the function. The pointer to array shows to the start, but doesn't have the length 'attached'. You can pass the length as parameter, as a member of a struct or class object or as global variable. Or you can use some library which has a struct or class to bundle the pointer and the length together. In languages where the array knows its size the array is not a simple pointer, it is a structure or class.

If you would use a library with some nice array implementation which bundles the length with the pointer to pass to your library's function, think if the users of your library will like this library dependency.

Note: the length of the data and the size of the allocated memory are two different things. if the array should be read by the function, then we pass the length, a count of items filed in the array. If the function should write into the array, the we usually pass the size of the array. If you have a reference to the array, then the compiler knows the size and you can use it at compile time.